# $\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|-\inf_{x\in I}|f(x)| \le \sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)$ and $\left|\;\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\right| \le \int_0^1|f(x)|dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

$f(x)$ is a bounded real valued function on the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Show that for any closed interval $I \subseteq [0,1]$, $$\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|-\inf_{x\in I}|f(x)| \le \sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)$$

and show that $$\left|\;\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\right| \le \int_0^1|f(x)|dx$$ for all function $f$ which are Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**: (1) If $f \ge 0$, then $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs f = f$, so there is nothing to show, if $f \le 0$, we have $\abs f = -f$, hence $\sup \abs f = -\inf f$ and $\inf \abs f = -\sup f$, that is also equality. If $f$ changes sign, we have $\sup f \le \sup\abs f$ and $\inf f < \inf \abs f$.

(2)Approximate the integral by Riemann sums and use the triangle inequality for sums.

Comment: How does $\sup f \le \sup\abs f$ and $\inf f < \inf \abs f$ this imply the result?